# My program terminates when I take number of test case =1. Other wise, it gives correct answer but skips the last testcase

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve this https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/351101/dashboard#s=p1 practice problem from Google codejam 2010 and here is my solution.
http://ideone.com/j8Q8f5

```
getline(cin,s);
```

I'm having problem when using getline function. What is wrong with my code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's because after you read number of test cases, your input stream is still on the same line. So the very first `getline` you call will always return you an empty string (the remainder of the first line with the number of test cases).

Just add

```
string dummy;
getline(cin, dummy);
```

right after you scan `t`: http://ideone.com/bunejC